# python how to run python without specifying the interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, permission-denied

when you run a python script, you have to do

```
python3 filename
```

Is there something you can write in the python file to make it so that you dont have to say python3 before running it.  I tried the #!/ line, but when I do:

```
./filename
```

it says permission denied.  Is specifying the interpreter name when running the program mandatory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of your python file, you'll want to add the path to the Python3 binary. This is commonly referred to as a "hashbang" or "shebang". It tells your shell *how* to interpret or run your file (without it, if you tried `./<python-file>`, it would try to interpret it as `bash`.

```
#!/path/to/python3
```

On my computer, it's

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

To determine the path where your `python3` binary (or link) is located, run

```
$ which python3
```

Alternatively, it's better to use `env`, as it will ensure the interpreter used is the first one on your environment's `$PATH`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Note, you'll need to run

```
$ chmod a+x <python-file>
```

to change the mode to make it executable. The `a` tells it to make it executable for all (user, group, and others), so if you do not want this, you can leave it out (as in, `chmod +x <python-file>`).

To not have to run `./` before the executable, you'll want to set your `PATH` as

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

in your `.bashrc` or similar `*rc` file for your shell. (`export` makes the variable available to sub-processes.) Then you'll want to run

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Where would you set your path?

Comment: Assuming you're in `bash` or `zsh`, in your shell, try just typing `PATH=$PATH:.`, and then typing the name of your script (assuming your hashbang is in place).

Comment: Just to be sure we're clear, you don't add `export PATH=$PATH:.` to your Python script, you add it to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (or add `setenv PATH ${PATH}:.` to your `~/.cshrc` or `~/.tcshrc`) scripts. Then, as I mention above, you `source ~/.bashrc` to have the changes occur in the current login shell (otherwise, you'll need to open a new shell).

Comment: Yeah idk what the problem is, i did all that, and i still have to put ./ before the pythonfile

Comment: What does it say when you try running your Python script without `./`?

Comment: the file is called simp.py, -bash: simp.py: command not found.

Comment: Try running in your `bash` shell: `PATH=$PATH:.`, then try running `simp.py` again. Ensure you're getting the `.` at the end of `PATH=$PATH:.`, as this typo could cause the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Ok, thats weird, now it works...  Does the Path variable just hold a place to look for the file?

Comment: It seems i can only use simp.py when im in the home directory though.

Comment: If `simp.py` is located in the home directory, then yes, you'll only be able to run it as `simp.py` in your home directory. Otherwise, you'll have to run it as `~/simp.py`. If you'd like to be able to run `simp.py` as `simp.py` in any directory, you'll want to add `PATH=$PATH:$HOME` or run `sudo ln -s ~/simp.py /usr/local/bin/simp`. Creating a link in a place already on the path would allow you to run `simp` and have it execute.

Comment: If you set the path variable so many times, how does it know which one to use, like my .bash_profile has 4 different declarations of PATH each with a different path to python, and it always runs python3.5, how does it know which PATH to use?

Comment: You're hopefully setting `PATH=$PATH:<something>` each time, which appends the new path (e.g., /usr/local/bin) to the `PATH` environment variable. How does it know which Python to use? I assume you mean which Python to use in `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, in that case, as I said in my answer, it looks at the *first* `python3` located in `PATH`. Furthermore, when you type `python3` on the command line, it's looking for the first `python3` on your `PATH`.

Comment: My first python3 is python in path is 3.4, but the next one is python3.5 but it always does python3.5

Comment: So what you can do is specifically target `python3.4` if you so desire. In your script, just change the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.4` or change it to specifically target the python3.4 binary: `#!/usr/bin/python3.4` (or wherever it's located -- do a `$ which python3.4` and copy that path.

Comment: Yeah my 3.5 is in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin for some reason...

Comment: Would it be better to just switch it to /usr/bin?

Comment: You shouldn't move it anywhere or switch it. Do a `$ which python3`. Your python3 binary is likely linked to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python` or somesuch. To check this, do an `ls -l` on the path that `which` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are on a linux or unix bases operating system. Yes there is something you can do. Hopefully you are using the `import os` and `import sys` library for any interaction with terminal. Next you have to do a `chmod` command on the file to make it `executable`

The command would be

`chmod +x [python_file.py]`

or usually (if not root)

`sudo chmod +x [python_file.py]`

Comment: And don't forget the path as in @Michael answer.

Comment: Yes, that works the file is an interpreter for a simple language im makeing, but is there any way to not have to put ./ before the file?  Like in java you dont need to put ./java filename.

Comment: This is a linux thing. So if you don't put `./` than you aren't looking in the same directory you are in. `python3` is recognized by your terminal as a command it knows which folder it is located in (because it is a PATH variable). If you want to have a command available in your terminal always you need to look up `PATH` variables and how to create and add them. Otherwise you have to say, hey i want to run `python_file.py` from the directory I am in, by saying `./python_file.py` or `path/to/file/python_file.py` from another folder.

Comment: This should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts

Comment: Also, path variables should only be very very commonly used (like python). If you only use a script a couple times, it probably isn't worth creating a path variable, just put the script in an easy to access folder. Just a hint.

Comment: How would I set the path to the python_file.py?

Comment: PATH is a global variable for you scripting language (or terminal). I recommend going to the link I added in a previous comment. Please be aware that if you change PATH variables or delete old ones you could possibly remove old things like `python3`. Please be careful when editting such things. I think putting the `chmod` file in `/opt/bin` folder should work, but you didn't even tell us what OS you are using so it's hard to know. The link I posted gives tons of methods of accomplishing this task, but you are getting off topic of the question.